# How to sort text from a file, format and print to cmd?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am very new to java. I need to write a program that reads a txt file with data like this:

```
Franklin,Benjamin,74,bcbs of Oklahoma,18
Hamilton,Alexander,199,aetna,25
Thatcher,Margaret,65,aflack,3
Nixon,Richard,45,kaiser permanente,7
```

Where the data is first name, last name, age, company, room number. The program should take these strings (?) and format them into a table that prints to the cmd prompt which should look like this:

```
Last       First           Age   Insurance            RoomHamilton
```

with the names and numbers in columns below.

I know this should have something to do with an ArrayList, but I'm truly lost.

Comment: If you're lost you should be talking to your teacher, not asking here.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn what this site is about and what is on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can get you started, yes you should use lists.

```
try {
        /** Reads all the lines of a file, and loops through each line */
        for (final String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("PATH_TO_FILE_HERE"))) {
            /** To show you what the line looks like */
            System.out.println(line);
            /** Splits each line by commas */
            String[] data = line.split(",");
            /**
             * Format the data here, then store it into a list
             */
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To print to the command console...

```
/** On all operating systems... */
private String[] generateLaunchArgs(String exe) {
    final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (os.toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
        return new String[] { "cmd", "/c", exe };
    }
    return new String[] { "bash", "-c", exe };
}

public void printToConsole(String message) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(generateLaunchArgs("echo " + message));
}
```